# How to register GuiceFilter programmatically?

Tags: jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, jersey, guice, servlet-listeners

I'm trying out a jersey application with guice dependency injection. Everything works fine when I load the `GuiceFilter` through web.xml. But when I register the filter using guice api as given below, jersey do not get initialized.

```
protected void configureServlets() {
    final Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put(PackagesResourceConfig.PROPERTY_PACKAGES, "com.mypackage.rest");
    bind(MyInterface.class).to(MyImpl.class);
    filter("/*").through(GuiceFilter.class);
    serve("/*").with(GuiceContainer.class, params);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to register Guice filter inside Guice filter. It should be registered directly in your servlet container, in `web.xml` or in the code which creates your servlet container (embedded Jetty, for example). Other servlets and filters, on the other hand, can be registered in Guice filter.

If you won't register Guice filter in your servlet container, how it would know that you want to pass your requests through this filter?

Comment: So, what do you suggest if I want to load the GuiceFilter without using web.xml? I tried creating a filter which extends GuiceFilter and used @WebFilter annotation to load it as a filter. It works fine. Is it a good approach?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know. I haven't used JEE annotations yet. However, whatever the way you set up the filter, writing `filter("/*").through(GuiceFilter.class)` is not quite right, unless you *really* want to run Guice filter inside Guice filter.